# Equality of p-value for cor t-test and anova F-test in simple linear regression

Tags: anova, t-test, p-value, linear-model, f-test

p-value for y, cor.test and F-test is the same 0.24 for below code. I assume this is due to F = t^2, but not entirely sure why.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(20, 10, 5)
y = rnorm(20, 50, 15)
cor(x,y)
summary(lm(x~y))
cor.test(x,y)
anova(lm(x~y))
```